# How do for/in loops work in Javascript? codecademy exercise

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is the second time I'm going through the Javascript lesson in codecademy as a refresher and there's something I don't quite understand. In on exercise called 'Contact List Project', the following is supposed to be the end code as provided by the lesson for viewing example.

```
var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
    };
    friends.steve = {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobs",
      number: "(408) 555-5555",
      address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
    };

    var list = function(obj) {
      for(var prop in obj) {
        console.log(prop);
      }
    };

    var search = function(name) {
      for(var prop in friends) {
        if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
          console.log(friends[prop]);
          return friends[prop];
        }
      }
    };

    list(friends);
    search("Steve");
```

The code produces the following result in the console:

```
bill
steve
{ firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Jobs',
  number: '(408) 555-5555',
  address: [ '1 Infinite Loop', 'Cupertino', 'CA', '95014' ] }
{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Jobs","number":"(408) 555-5555","address":["1 Infinite Loop","Cupertino","CA","95014"]}
```

How exactly does the for/in loop work? I understand that  is just a placeholder but why does list(friends) come up with just 'bill' and 'steve'? Isn't it supposed to run through all the properties of an object?

Answer (score 0):

It is running through all of the properties of the `friends` object. This object only has 2 properties, `bill` and `steve` as defined here:

```
var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      ...
    };
    friends.steve = {
      ...
    };
```

All of the sub-properties within these two are not relevant to the initial for/in loop. The `search` function is what prints them out once it finds the one with `firstName === 'steve'`

Comment: Codecademy refers to 'bill' and 'steve' as keys to the object i.e. obj.[key] and it refers to it's sub-properties as 'properties'. Are these terms (keys, properties, sub-properties) interchangeable or do they have specific definitions that I'm just not getting? If you could shed a little bit of light in that, thank you in advance.

Comment: properties are made up of a key and a value. here bill is a key and steve is a key  and the objects they are equal to are their values.

Comment: Thank you that helped. One last question, why does the code need to have `list(friends);` in order for `search("Steve");` to run? Aren't those functions independent of each other?

Comment: It doesn't! it's just there to show you the properties. If you comment out the `list(friends)` line you'll see that search works just fine. `list()` is simply printing them to console (or "listing" them) for you to see

Answer (score 0):

I think an in-depth look at `Object.defineProperty()` described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) will clear your confusion about `property`, `key` & `value`.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: 'static'
});
```

Comment: he's not using `Object.defineProperty()`, so how will this clear up his confusion?

Comment: Confusion about properties and keys as evident from his expectation in the question and in the comment to the other answer.

Comment: It looks like his confusion is about objects that are nested in other objects. He doesn't understand hierarchy. I'm not sure how the documentation of `defineProperty()` will help with that.